# Giving text input the remaining width

Tags: css, html

I have a label, input and button one line. The width of the label and button are dynamic, they take the width of the text they contain. The label is aligned to the left, and the button to the right.

I want the button to be aligned to the far right, and the input in the middle take up all the remaining space.

I put a `float: right` on the button, but if I put the width of the input to `100%` it goes to the next line and acts like a block element.

What would be the best / easiest way to realize what I'm trying to do here? This is a little bit tricky for me. I'm not sure what to do.

```css
label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
input[type=text] {
  width: 355px; /*100% doesnt work*/
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
button {
  margin-left: -1px;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="last">
  <label for="place">Any text here:</label>
  <input type="text" id="place" value="Test value">
  <button>Click</button>
</fieldset>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edLu6zw8/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bit of a hacky way to do it:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.fixedText {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.relativeText {
  width: 100%;
  }
#place {
  width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixedText">
      <label for="place">Any text here:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="relativeText">
      <input type="text" id="place" value="Test value">
    </td>
    <td class="fixedText">
      <button>Click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this maybe possible to realize without any HTML tables?

Comment: You could use any other element, but you'd need `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.  You probably should use the table unless you want to use JavaScript.  Please accept this answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you that you can also do it without tables (although I would probably go for the `display: table-cell`).

First float the `label` and the `button` to the left and right. Add a wrapper around the `input`. The wrapper gets `overflow: hidden` which creates a new block formatting context, see http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/ for background information. In short this allow the wrapper to take up the remaining space.

Afterwards we apply some fixes to the `padding`, `box-sizing`, `height` and `line-height` to make it all look good again.

```css
label {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;        
}
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
button {
  margin-left: -1px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="last">
  <label for="place">Any text here:</label>
  <button>Click</button>
  <div class="wrapper"><input type="text" id="place" value="Test value"></div>
</fieldset>
```